# Retrieve data from firebase and create marker

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i would like to ask how to retrieve the data from firebase which is to get specific data.
My firebase database is look like this.[image: My firebase database is look like this.]. 
i want to retrieve the data in the circle.

full firebase will look like this.
[image]

what have i try is to use datasnapshot and value eventlistener to call data from firebase.

```
private void getMarkerFromDb()
    {
        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference dataMarker = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        if (getIntent()!=null) {

            lrpTest = (LRP_model) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lrp");

            DatabaseReference routeRef = dataMarker.child("LRP")
                    .child(userId)
                    .child("route_models");
            routeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (int counter =0; counter<dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();counter++) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ss : dataSnapshot.child("route_models").getChildren()) {
                            double latitude = ss.child("rtLat").getValue(Double.class);
                            double longitude = ss.child("rtLng").getValue(Double.class);
                            LatLng loc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("test")).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pole));
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The ouput is not showing anything.

Comment: Please upload pictures of database

Comment: done adding the picture of firebase

Comment: use Double.parseDouble(strvalue) to get double value

Comment: how can i use that because before this still got error

Comment: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to double. it just said like this.

Comment: are you able to receive lat,long in string format? if yes then convert that string into double value by using double = Double.parseDouble(strLatvalue)

Comment: failed to receive the lat long.

Comment: thanks i got the solution. double =Double.parseDouble(strLatValue).toString;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
            routeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (int counter =0; counter<dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();counter++) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ss : dataSnapshot.child("route_models").getChildren()) {
                            double latitude = ss.child("rtLat").getValue(Double.class);
                            double longitude = ss.child("rtLng").getValue(Double.class);
                            LatLng loc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("test")).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pole));
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

into this:

```
            DatabaseReference routeRef = dataMarker.child("LRP")
                    .child(userId);

            routeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ss : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot datas : ss.child("route_models").getChildren()) {
                            double latitude = datas.child("rtLat").getValue(Double.class);
                            double longitude = datas.child("rtLng").getValue(Double.class);
                            LatLng loc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("test")).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pole));
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Change the reference to node `userId`, then iterate twice inside of it to access `route_models` attributes.

Comment: okay remove the for loop and just log the datasnapshot: `Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot);` also log the `userId`

Comment: D/MapActivity: DataSnapshot { key = NwyIA1AVOnMA8ZK46CNeVR1sVnd2, value = null }data

Comment: 2019-07-11 16:35:54.620 13377-13377/com.example.application.distriulam D/MapActivity: NwyIA1AVOnMA8ZK46CNeVR1sVnd2 userId

Comment: if you change your reference to this `DatabaseReference routeRef = dataMarker.child("LRP")
                    .child(userId)
                    .child("-LeoD6JYtBj9dEV71AX9");` and log as before `Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot);` and tell me what do you get

Comment: it list out the data from the firebase in the Log.

Comment: sir help me out at create the uid please.

Comment: sir the problem is i could not get .child(uid) after current user id. It still not showing anything

Comment: I didnt understand, what do you mean? You are getting the current user id, what you are not getting is what is inside the user id.

Comment: owh i mean the second key in the firebase

Comment: i want  to get the id of the second uid firebase, which is the key we are testing  .child("-LeoD6JYtBj9dEV71AX9") here.

Comment: Then inside the first loop do `String key = ss.getKey()`

Comment: Okey sir, the log return the key but not getting the value under the key.

Comment: the second loop not retrieve the data when i try to do the log.